# Tests execution errors

Tags: typescript, testing

I have created some tests in Jasmine for an Angular project generated by JHipster.

The result of test execution in PHantomJs is like this, but it is not clear if I have problems with test execution or the tests have failed. And which tests have failed. It does not give any detail. If somebody has done this, is this the normal way to output the results and how do you read it?

```html
        invokeTask@webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:495:0 <- spec/en
try.ts:146804:41
        invoke@webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:484:0 <- spec/entry.
ts:146793:53
        timer@webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:2065:0 <- spec/entry.
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 499 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 58.0
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 500 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 58.1
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 501 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 58.1
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 502 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 58.3
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 503 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 58.4
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 504 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 58.6
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 505 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 58.7
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 506 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 58.9
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 507 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 59.0
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 508 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 59.0
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 509 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 59.1
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 510 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 59.2
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 511 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 59.3
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 512 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 59.5
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 513 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 59.7
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 514 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 59.8
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 515 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 59.8
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 516 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 59.9
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 517 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 59.9
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 518 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 1 mi
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 519 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 1 mi
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 520 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 1 mi
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 521 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 1 mi
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 522 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 1 mi
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 523 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 1 mi
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 524 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 1 mi
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 525 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 1 mi
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 526 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 1 mi
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 527 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 1 mi
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 528 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 1 mi
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 529 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 1 mi
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 530 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 1 mi
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 531 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 1 mi
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 532 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 1 mi
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 533 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 1 mi
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 534 of 534 (32 FAILED) (0 secs / 1 mi
n 1.527 secs)

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 534 of 534 (32 FAILED) (1 min 7.256 se
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 534 of 534 (32 FAILED) (1 min 7.256 se
cs / 1 min 1.527 secs)

=============================== Coverage summary ===============================

Statements   : 68.58% ( 12019/17525 )
Branches     : 28.79% ( 412/1431 )
Functions    : 44.48% ( 2314/5202 )
Lines        : 66.88% ( 10778/16116 )
================================================================================

27 04 2018 09:24:47.474:WARN [launcher]: PhantomJS was not killed in 2000 ms, se
nding SIGKILL.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! oncosup@0.0.0 test: `npm run lint && karma start src/test/javascript/ka
rma.conf.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the oncosup@0.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.
```